# How do I prompt the user to run program again?

Tags: java

After hours of research I was able to come up with a while loop that should help. Only problem is that it loops and doesn't ask the user to run again. It just loops the golf program over and over. Can anyone point out what went wrong? Currently in a beginning class, so I may not understand a whole lot.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GolfEM
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    
        boolean go = true;
        boolean run = true;

        while (go==true)
        {
            while (run)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter par for the hole: ");
                int par = kb.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter the number of strokes: ");
                int stroke = kb.nextInt();
                {

                    if (stroke==1)  
                    {
                        System.out.println("hole in one");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (3==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("double eagle");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (2==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("eagle");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (1==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("birdie");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (par==stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("par");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (-1==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("bogey");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (-2==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("double-bogey");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (-3==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("triple-bogey");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (-4==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("four-over-par");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (-5==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("five-over-par");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (-6==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("six-over-par");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else if (-7==par-stroke)
                    {
                        System.out.println("seven-over-par");
                        run=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Better luck next time");
                        run=false;
                    }
                }
            }
            run=false;
        }
        if (run==false)
            System.out.println("Run again? ");

        char again = kb.next().charAt(0);

        if (again == 'y')
        {
            run=true;
        }
        else if (again == 'n')
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            go = false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("Invalid answer");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the first time I see a question with five tags none of which is relevant. You should use tags to specify things like which language you use, not just type five words that happen to appear in your question.

Comment: You'll find programming easier if you use decent indentation.

Comment: And any good java IDE should be able to reformat code with indentation. I use CTRL-ALT-L all the time :)

Comment: Any good brain should not need a GUI to do indentation for you. It's _really_ easy, trust me.

Comment: Sometimes people need all the help they can get... :)

Comment: you really should use a switch statement instead of if else if else if else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by other members, use decent indentation.

Here, you just misplaced few braces.

Corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class GolfEM
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean go = true;
boolean run = true;
while (go==true)
    {
    while (run)
        {
System.out.println("Enter par for the hole: ");
int par = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the number of strokes: ");
int stroke = kb.nextInt();


if (stroke==1)  {
System.out.println("hole in one");
run=false;
        }
else
if (3==par-stroke){
System.out.println("double eagle");
run=false;
        }
else
if (2==par-stroke){
System.out.println("eagle");
run=false;
        }
else
if (1==par-stroke){
System.out.println("birdie");
run=false;
        }
else
if (par==stroke){
System.out.println("par");
run=false;
        }
else
if (-1==par-stroke){
System.out.println("bogey");
run=false;
        }
else
if (-2==par-stroke){
System.out.println("double-bogey");
run=false;
        }
else
if (-3==par-stroke){
System.out.println("triple-bogey");
run=false;
        }
else
if (-4==par-stroke){
System.out.println("four-over-par");
run=false;
        }
else
if (-5==par-stroke){
System.out.println("five-over-par");
run=false;
        }
else
if (-6==par-stroke){
System.out.println("six-over-par");
run=false;
        }
else
if (-7==par-stroke){
System.out.println("seven-over-par");
run=false;
        }
else{
System.out.println("Better luck next time");
run=false;
        }
           run=false;
        }


    if (run==false)
    System.out.println("Run again? ");
    char again = kb.next().charAt(0);
        if (again == 'y')
        {
        run=true;}
        else if (again == 'n')
        {
        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        go = false;}
        else
        {
        System.err.println("Invalid answer");
        }}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things wrong with your code.

1. outer go loop is pretty useless, so remove it altogether
2. your if else blocks are super ugly looking. Switch statements are much more concise
3. no real point to set run=false every case, just do it at the end
4. Your response will exit on an invalid character

I changed the code below. Have a looksie.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class GolfEM
{ 
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    
        boolean run = true;

        while (run)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter par for the hole: ");
            int par = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of strokes: ");
            int stroke = kb.nextInt();                

            if (stroke==1)  {
                System.out.println("hole in one");
                run=false;
            }
            else{
                switch(par-stroke){
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("double eagle");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("eagle");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("birdie");
                        break;

                    case 0:   
                        System.out.println("par");
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        System.out.println("bogey");
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        System.out.println("double-bogey");
                        break;
                    case -3:
                        System.out.println("triple-bogey");
                        break;
                    case -4:
                        System.out.println("four-over-par");
                        break;
                    case -5:
                        System.out.println("five-over-par");
                        break;
                    case -6:
                        System.out.println("six-over-par");
                        break;
                    case -7:
                        System.out.println("seven-over-par");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Better luck next time");

                }

            }                           
            run=false;        

            while(1){
                System.out.println("Run again? ");
                char again = kb.next().charAt(0);
                if (again == 'y')
                {
                run=true;
                break;
                }
                else if (again == 'n')
                {
                System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("Invalid answer");
                }
            }
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I can give some pointers, you don't need two while loops here. You really just need one (let's say, the outer one, the 'go' loop).

Your logic should then be like this...

```
    boolean go = true;
    while (go) {
         // get input...
         // compute the result for this hole...
         // get user input...
         // decide whether to go again (go = false; or go = true;)
    }
```

Be careful of the curly braces. Like other people suggested, start by properly indenting your code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really see what the inner `run` loop is for. It runs exactly once and then `run` is set to false. However, I'll assume that your code is preliminary and that this part will get filled in later.

About your actual problem: Your program runs in an infinite loop, because the part asking the user whether to run the program again is *outside* of the `go` loop. Just move that part one "curly brace" level up and you should be fine.